# Multiple dropdown and textbox filter using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table where i bind all the json data using ngrepeat. Now my task is to filter based the column. I have two dropdown lists and a text box control. It has to perform all sort of search based on both DDL selected values and textbox value.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to filter the table based on the DDL and Textbox values

Comment: DDL = DropDownList in ASP.NET. <asp:DropDownList> is equivalent to <select> in html.

Comment: @user5383264 We need to see what code have you achieved. Can you update your question with your code?